# Loop showing menu never ends

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to write a simple menu in C.

This is my proposed code:

```
while (end == 0) {

    printf("Main menu\n");
    printf("=========\n");
    printf("1) Option 1.\n");
    printf("2) Option 2.\n");
    printf("3) Option 3.\n");
    printf("4) Option 4.\n");
    printf("0) Exit");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Choose an option: ");
    fgets(&menu_option,1,stdin);

    switch (menu_option) {
        case '0': end = 1; break;
        case '1': option1(); break;
        case '2': option2(); break;
        case '3': option3(); break;
        case '4': option4();
    }

}
```

However, when executing this code, the loop never ends.

What's wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT: when I say "the loop never ends", I want to say that I can't write any option because the menu appears again and again.

Comment: `fgets(&menu_option,1,stdin);` Buffer size is too small.

Comment: Are you sure, `menu_option` get '0'? Add debug point

Comment: When I say "the loop never ends", I want to say that I can't write any option because the menu appears again and again.

Comment: Why is buffer size too small? I only want to read one character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fgets.html)

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a  is read and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The string is then terminated with a null byte.

Since you give a length of `1`, `n-1` will be `0` and so your input is never stored in `menu_option`. Change it to a char array

```
char menu_option[10];
// ...
fgets(menu_option, sizeof(menu_option), stdin);

switch (menu_option[0]) {
    case '0': end = 1; break;
    case '1': option1(); break;
    case '2': option2(); break;
    case '3': option3(); break;
    case '4': option4();
}
```

*Update:*

It is necessary to use char arrays, because you need enough space to store the input. The minimum size for a buffer is two characters, e.g. `char buf[2]`, because `fgets` stores your input plus a terminating `NUL` character.

The loop iterates twice or even more times, because when you input e.g. <kbd>1 return</kbd> or <kbd>1 3 2 return</kbd>, it will first return `1`, then `3`, `2` and finally <kbd>return</kbd>. If you want to read the whole line and use the first digit only, your buffer must be larger than just 2, like e.g. 10 or even 256.

Comment: No need for 10, 2 would be enough :)

Comment: Would it be convenient to use a buffer with length of `2`? In that case, `n-1`would be `1` and what I've written should work, shouldn't it? (without using char arrays)

Comment: @baister Yes, your buffer can be as small as 2, of course. Why do you want to avoid a char array?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Because I don't know why it is necessary. However, I've checked that if I use a char (not array) and set a buffer with a length of just `2`, after choosing an option the loop iterates twice. Using a buffer with length of `3`, it works fine. That's a bit strange for me.

Comment: @baister In C, strings are char arrays of minimum length 1 (which contains just string terminating NUL character, meaning the string length can't be more than 0). So if you want a string which will actually contain something, you need a char array size 2 or more. As to why you need strings, it's because you use `fgets`, which reads string.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` reads a string instead of character.  The statement

```
fgets(&menu_option,1,stdin);
```

Will store a string to `menu_option` but to store a string you need a size at least `2` bytes.

```
char menu_option[2];  
...
fgets(menu_option,2,stdin);   
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);  // This will be needed to flush your input buffer 
switch (menu_option[0]) {
        ...
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

> **fgets**
>
> `char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );`
>
> Get string from stream.
>
> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C
>   string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a
>   newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.
>
> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a
>   valid character by the function and included in the string copied to
>   str.
>
> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the
>   characters copied to str.

Since you have specified 1 for the number, 0 bytes are read, and the only thing that happens is that a terminating null character is appended. The result is an infinite loop in which nothing is read.

Answer (score 1):

Since in the comments you expressed dislike for using strings, here's alternative implementation with minimal changes to the question code:

```
while (end == 0) {

    printf("...menu print snipped...\n");

    int ch = getchar();

    switch (ch) {
        case EOF: // end of file or error, fall through to exit option
        case '0': end = 1; break;
        case '1': option1(); break;
        case '2': option2(); break;
        case '3': option3(); break;
        case '4': option4();
        // default: // add error message? 
    }

    // ignore any extra chars in the same line
    while ((ch = getchar() != '\n') {
        // test for end of file and set end to true
        if (ch == EOF) {
            end = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the extra loop, which will read and discard rest of the input line. Without it, user can enter several options on one line, which is probably not desirable. Also note, if the option functions read more user input, consider how you handle long lines then. For example move the extra loop to be before switch (and add another variable to read discarded chars). Actually you should probably put the extra loop to it's own function `discard_until_newline`.